# How to customize font-faces in java spring

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, font-face

In java spring project there is special instruction to mapping files, 
I have try mapping my css file and it's working fine , but @font-faces built in bootstrap.css not working
 see example :

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

in  mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

in header.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${baseURL}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${baseURL}/resources/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" />" />
```

bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

when deploy font on real example, result showing :

[image]

reference to correct implementation glyphicon iconic font : [twitter-bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify url mapping and mime type of the font in web.xml

For mapping fonts you can do something like this in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/font/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and for mapping the mime types you can do something like this

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

for other type of fonts you can do something like

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

This thing worked in my case, hope this works with you as well.